# Why are (Hausdorff) locally compact groups interesting?

Tags: soft-question, fourier-analysis, topological-groups, locally-compact-groups

I am currently taking classes in *Combinatorics* and *Abstract Harmonic Analysis*, which deal with the Fourier Analysis of functions on (mostly Hausdorff) locally compact topological (mostly abelian) groups. However, I cannot find sufficient motivation for this study, i.e., why *just* (Hausdorff) locally compact (abelian) groups? **Why not any other group**, even a ring, or some devilish algebraic structure?

It'd be helpful if the folks at MSE could highlight the said motivations, possibly in terms of examples of useful and pivotal connections with other areas of mathematics, interesting results, conjectures, etc. Thank you!

---

[This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1584321/importance-of-locally-compact-hausdorff-spaces) is somewhat helpful but not thoroughly satisfying. Among other things, it doesn't seem to talk about *why* other algebraic structures are *not* used, for instance.

Comment: The [Wikipeda page for locally compact group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_compact_group) points out that such groups have a translation-invariant Borel measure. This means some functions can be averaged over the group, much like one would do when working with  representations of finite groups.

Comment: This related [Math Overflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/328037/interesting-examples-of-non-locally-compact-topological-groups) might be useful too

Comment: To do analysis on topological groups, in particular, integration theory and get nice results such as invariant measure under group operation (Haar measures), Fubini's theorem, representations theorems etc., locally compact topologies are the most general spaces in which difficulties have been overcome; many applications stay within this framework. As for why groups and not other structures, groups seem to be the most basic structure upon which one does analysis (Fourier analysis) with useful applications (via group actions)